# convert signed byte to unsigned byte using formula int unsignedByte = signedByte >= 0 ? signedByte : 256 + signedByte;

Tags: java, byte, unsigned, sign

Someone has told me that to convert an signed byte to an unsigned byte in java, we can use the formula

```
int unsignedByte = signedByte >= 0 ? signedByte : 256 + signedByte;
```

But for example, if I have a signedByte value of 1 (byte value range from -128 to 127), and I use this formula, so `1 >= 0` evaluates to `true`, therefore the first expression is used, resulting in `1 + 1`, which equal to `2`. But I was expecting that the same number represented by 129 in unsignedByte?

Is there something wrong with my understanding or this formula is wrong?

An example with actual signed and unsigned value would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand the ternary operator:

```
int unsignedByte =
   signedByte >= 0 ? 
      signedByte  // you get this
      : 256 + signedByte; // or this
```

and not

```
int unsignedByte =
   (signedByte >= 0 ? signedByte  : 256) 
   + signedByte;
```

Comment: so if I have a signed byte with value 1, signedByte >= 0 evaluates to true, the int unsignedByte = 1? But I thought int unsignedByte should be equal to 129?

Comment: *"unsignedByte = 1? But I thought int unsignedByte should be equal to 129?"* No, that's wrong. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Just to be safe, you could always put the `256 + signedByte` in parens and thereby eliminate all posssible doubt.

Comment: @Captain America, you asked for the value itself when `>=0`, so you got `1`. "Unsigned" means "positive", yes? And `1` is positive, yes? So the "unsigned" value of `1` is ... `1`, yes?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the bitwise AND operator like so:

```
int unsignedByte = signedByte&255;
```

Essentially this increases the space allowed which in turn changes the bit that dictates whether it's negative to a higher bit (31 at 0 index
)